# Dynamically add scrollable tab mdl react ?

Tags: reactjs, layout, dynamic, tabs, material-design

I'm using material design lite and react. I managed to add dynamically tab when using separate layout and tabs but when I try to use mdl-layout__tab-bar mdl-js-ripple-effect I can't update the layout so the tab isn't working.

```
<div className="mdl-layout mdl-js-layout mdl-layout--fixed-header">
        <header className="mdl-layout__header">
            <div className="mdl-layout__header-row">
                <span className="mdl-layout-title">Title</span>
            </div>
            <div className="mdl-layout__tab-bar mdl-js-ripple-effect">
                {
                    this.state.tabs.map((tab, i) => {
                        let tabId = '#' + tab.id;
                        let className = 'mdl-layout__tab';
                        tab.active ? className += ' is-active' : className + '';

                        return <a key={i} href={tabId} className={className}>{tab.name}</a>
                    })
                }
                <a key={this.state.tabs.length} href='#add-new'
                   className={'mdl-layout__tab ' + ADD_NEW}>+</a>
            </div>
        </header>
        <div className="mdl-layout__drawer">
            <span className="mdl-layout-title">Title</span>
            <nav className="mdl-navigation">
                <a className="mdl-navigation__link" href="">Link</a>
                <a className="mdl-navigation__link" href="">Link</a>
                <li>
                    <hr/>
                </li>
                <span className="asdf">
                    <a className="mdl-navigation__link" href="">Add new</a>
                </span>
            </nav>
        </div>
        <main className="mdl-layout__content">
            {
                this.state.tabs.map((tab, i) => {
                    return <Tab key={i} id={tab.id} active={tab.active} content={tab.content}/>
                })
            }
            <Tab key={this.state.tabs.length} id='add-new' active={false}></Tab>
        </main>
    </div>;
```

This is my render function and the tab  element is added properly, but when I click on it the tabs panel isn't shown.

```
componentDidUpdate() {
    if (!this.layout) {
        this.layout = MaterialLayout.apply(MaterialLayout.prototype,[document.getElementsByClassName('mdl-layout')[0]]);
    }
    let id = this.state.tabs[this.state.tabs.length - 1].id;
    let tabs = document.getElementsByClassName('mdl-layout__tab-bar')[0].getElementsByTagName('a');
    let panels = document.getElementsByClassName('mdl-layout__content')[0].getElementsByClassName('mdl-layout__tab-panel ');
    MaterialLayoutTab(document.getElementsByTagName("a[href=" + id + "]"), tabs, panels, this.layout);
    this.registerListener();
    componentHandler.upgradeDom();
}
```

I tried anything but still can't upgrade the tabs ;/ 
Any suggestions will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution :

```
componentDidUpdate() {
if (!this.layout) {
  this.layout = document.getElementsByClassName('mdl-layout')[0];
} else {
  let id = '#' + this.state.tabs[this.state.tabs.length - 1].id;
  let tabs = document.getElementsByClassName('mdl-layout__tab-bar')[0].getElementsByTagName('a');
  let panels = document.getElementsByClassName('mdl-layout__content')[0].getElementsByClassName('mdl-layout__tab-panel ');
  console.log(tabs);
  for (let tab of tabs) {
    //document.querySelectorAll("a[href='" + id + "']"
    new MaterialLayoutTab(tab, tabs, panels, this.layout.MaterialLayout);
  }
}
this.registerListener();
}
```